# Gridview Row Editing Need to lock sorting to not be allowed while in Edit mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I discovered that when a ROW in my ASP.NET gridview is in Edit mode and I click on column sorting, that now I am actually editing something else.

1. The **business team doesn't want me to simply cancel the edit on a sort**
2. The **1 option is to force a lock on not Being able to SORT while in Edit mode**
3. **Or on the Sort that the Edit mode changes to the appropriate row that WAS in the edit mode before the grid sort.**

There are only like a dozen rows, so it is not like having to think and worry about paging on this Grid.

Either #2 or #3 are my choices but I don't see any feasible solutions so far.

Answer (score 1):

On a Gridview that has many columns, it can be a bit of an issue to change the SortExpression one at a time.  What I've done, in the `Gridview1_RowEditing` function is:

```
Gridview1.AllowSorting = false;
```

Then I set this back to `true` when the editing is completed or canceled.